# How to change background image based on screen size, possibly with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an `background-image:url` on my `body` in CSS. The problem is when I transition into mobile devices where the screen becomes portrait orientated. I have a different portrait orientated background I wish to use. Mainly, "portrait-orientated" in my case really just translates to mobile devices, not so much ipads/tablets. Mobiles are much more extreme with the difference between length and width so I want to link a different url in this case.

Idk if there's any way I could use Bootstrap's .hidden-xs/.visible-xs to accomplish this, that's just me thinking out loud, but if someone has a solution using this I'd be more than happy to hear it. This also would help since I'm using Bootstrap's navbar which changes into a touchscreen navbar when `xs`, meaning <768px, So I'd like to only change the background image when the navbar changes.

So any ideas? I'm a total newbie at this point, this is my first real project that isn't just isolated snippets. This might be something for Java but idk. I'd love any and all help.

Also a quick semi-related question, how do I handle `background-position: center (-50px from the top)`. Should I just take the picture I want to use and add 50px of whitespace on top with paint or whatever then upload that? Or is the a way to set this is CSS?

Comment: you could use CSS media queries, works with bootstrap

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `@media` queries to write window size specific css. Example:

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    .element {
        background: #cccccc;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .element {
        background: #888888;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .element {
        background: #222222;
    }
}
```

Here's is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhqn1vhh/

Comment: This won't help if the image comes from the server side obviously. Would be nice to provide a solution for that as well ;)  For example, image from server side might come and style tag generated on the fly on the body element.

Comment: This worked for me, just had to tweak with the amount of pixels for a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

[Media Queries - Bootstrap Grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

You could have something like this on your own CSS:

**Update**

Following @DaveL17 's comment, the code has been updated for newer versions

i.e. changing `image-url(...)` to `url(...)`

```css
@media (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 301px) and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/400/600");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/768");
  }
}
@media (min-width: 769px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
    background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/1048");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  html body
</body>
```

Comment: Just a quick note that the `image-url` attribute is now `url`.

`background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/800/1048");`

Answer (score 1):

i do it like this using bootstrap. but Im sure it would work without bootstrap.

```
.class {
    background-image: image-url("beach.jpg") ;
    min-height:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Also make sure that you have this in your html head- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Answer (score 0):

In order of implementing media queries, it is a better and more professional opinion that you use the  tag directly into the HTML containing source tag for different screen size.

Please find below an example implementation of this methodology:

```
 <picture>
  <source srcset="small-image.jpg" media="(max-width: 375px)">
  <source srcset="main-image.jpg">
  <img src="main-image.jpg" alt="" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).