# How do I have a different background color on the mobile view versus the desktop view?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to have a different background color for my website when viewed on a mobile device versus when viewed on a desktop? I know you can change it depending on the screen width, but I need it to be different for someone viewing it on an iPad as well, which is similar to the width of a desktop monitor, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Have a look at media queries in your css

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background image based on screen size, possibly with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704432/how-to-change-background-image-based-on-screen-size-possibly-with-bootstrap)

Comment: @jgetner
Including 
@ media (max-width:768px){
    body{background:red}
}

@ media (min-width:769px){
    body{background:blue}
}

in my code didn't appear to work. I changed it to the colors I wanted, however it didn't change with the screen width. The website is [link](https://Wallet.TheRavenCoinNest.com)

Comment: I checked the link and it works. Light background for wide screens and dark background for mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and it's very simple! The easiest solution is to apply CSS @media queries and you can specify exactly at which screen resolution the background color should change (or based on other features not only screen resolution!).

CSS @media has many features that you can set and you can read more at W3Schools [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```css
@media (max-width:768px){
    body{background:red}
}

@media (min-width:769px){
    body{background:blue}
}
```