# Can two different html codes exist for responsive web pages?

Tags: html, responsive-design

This isn't so much a problem as it is helping with brainstorming ideas. At least on the subject if an idea is valid or not. Now i know CSS imaging helps the page reshape when it hits, say, a tablet size screen or an iPhone sized screen. My question, is there a way to have two completely different designs set up to work when the pixel size hits a certain level?

Comment: Responsive Web Design (RWD) is a concept that applies not only for images but for the entire page as well.  The idea is that you create a single HTML code and the design is applied via CSS according to viewport size.  You do not need two HTML versions (but you do, sometimes, create code to accommodate one screen size vs and a separate code snippet to accommodate another one).  Search for Media Queries or see [this answer about media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28704608/600486)

Comment: btw, [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Stack Overflow is not a discussion board. Your question is also far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in CSS with something similar to this:

```
@media (min-width:500px) { … }
```

However, this method comes with its inherent problems. If a user rotates their phone sideways will they receive a different version of the page? If a user simply has their resolution turned down (or just have an old monitor), will they be stuck using a different version?

From how I read your question, it would appear as though you are simply trying to detect when someone is on a phone, and give them a mobile version of the site? If that is the case there is a better alternative using JavaScript:

```
function mobileMode(){
var x= navigator.userAgent;
if (x.indexOf('Mobile')>=0){
    //Do mobile stuff here
}
else{
    //Or do desktop stuff here if need be
}
```

Every browser sends what is called a user agent, and using this you can detect if someone is on mobile simply by checking for the word "Mobile" within their user agent.

Another advantage to this, is it allows someone on a phone to request the desktop version of the site.

Once you have detected the type of device viewing the page, you could even do something like change the link to an entirely different CSS file for mobile users!

Comment: I will try this, and return if i come across any issues.

Comment: you cannot rely on user agent (any more than viewport size, in any case) as this can be (and indeed, often is) easily spoofed - this is not the correct approach to RWD, btw.  Media queries is the best practices way of handling this

Comment: 1) if the user rotates their device, the viewport changes and the design you made for the given viewport changes accordingly 2) if user has low resolution, the viewport will reflect/detect that and handle it correctly to present the correct design.  Assumptions about the co-relation between user-agent and screen resolution were proven to be unreliable a long time ago.  This answer is actually leading you down the wrong approach to achieving RWD - use at your own peril

Comment: I would like to note that while the user agent can be spoofed, this is a non-issue. All the user is hurting by spoofing it is themselves. And there is actually a functional purpose behind allowing spoofing. If you're on your phone, and request the desktop version of the site, your browser spoofs the user agent, and reloads the page, showing you the desktop site. An implementation based upon viewport will not allow for this behavior, along with the aforementioned issues with a viewport implementation.